# UIColor(named:) always returns nil on iOS 11.0-11.2

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, ios11

I have a class that returns a UIColor from my custom palette. I call this programmatically but when I tested it on iOS 11 it always returns a `nil` result... I tried this on multiple devices and OS versions 11.0, 11.0.1, 11.2 and all of them returns `nil`. But as soon as I run them on >iOS 12 it always returns a correct color.

```
var color: UIColor? {
    switch self {
    case .darkIndigo: return UIColor(named: "darkIndigo")
    case .lightNavy: return UIColor(named: "lightNavy")
    case .cobalt: return UIColor(named: "cobalt")
    }
}
```

I have recently changed my bundle ID for the app... and this makes me think that it has something to do with the similar problem that UIImage has when multiple bundles are used. Especially when I get the error message

> WARNING: Unable to resolve the color named "darkIndigo" from any of the following bundles:

But how is this supposed to be resolved? Should I just manually remove the whole asset catalogue and add them back?

Comment: Are you using this from your app or from a  framework? Do you have the color assets in your main bundle?

Comment: by the way with an `enum X: String` the code could be written simply as `return UIColor(named: rawValue)`.

Comment: The color assets are in my main bundle and it's being used from my app...

Comment: I'm having this same issue. My only difference is that I have NOT recently changed the Bundle ID for my app. However, just like you, I'm getting a `nil` UIColor from <iOS 12. Interestingly, if I create a new project, `UIColor named:` works as expected, so it appears that there would be some setting that was made in my project that is preventing the Color Set from going into an iOS 11 bundle, but I wouldn't even begin to know where to start looking for such a setting.

Comment: I have requested code level support from Apple on the matter, so i'll keep you posted @Nick when I get the response.

Comment: @GiovanniPalusa did you get any help/response from Apple on this? I just downloaded the GM build of Xcode 11 and this problem still persists. I also don't have any physical devices running iOS 11, so I'm unable to check if it's a problem isolated to the Simulator, or Xcode as a whole.

Comment: Hi, I haven't heard anything yet. I will send them a reminder on the errand!

Comment: I have also tried reproducing the problem in a separate project, but with no success... anyone else that have succeeded with that? Then I could send that project to apple to test

Comment: @Nick - I have tried on devices running iOS 11, and the app crashes instantly

Comment: The really interesting/annoying part is that I tried to strip down my project to also send to Apple, so I deleted everything in the Storyboard as well as all classes other than appDelegate.h/.m. I put a blank ViewController in the Storyboard and ran my app and it worked with no issue. I'm even more confused now than I was when I started! I'm going to now try deleting things more or less one at a time to see if I can find what causes it to start working

Comment: It's been solved now in Xcode 11 GM seed 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Edit:

This was a bug in Xcode and its fixed in the new GM Seed 2 (11A420a).

---

I encountered this issue as well. I was using Xcode 11 beta 6, with Command Line Tools 11.0.

I solved it by switching to Xcode 10.2.1 and Command Line Tools 10.2.1, cleaning & building again.

[image: Xcode Command Line Tools]

Comment: Thank you! I am also encountering this with Xcode 11 beta 6.

Comment: Encountering this on Xcode 11 beta 7 as well. There must be issues in the beta in compiling asset catalogs.

Comment: Also seeing this on Beta 7! Since we're so late in the beta cycle, I'm going to wrap it in an availability check unfortunately, doubt a fix is coming before GM

Comment: Definitely an XCode Beta bug. Seeing some mentions of it in this thread (and many separate threads): https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/121631

Comment: Apple just released an Xcode 11 GM2 to resolve this issue. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_release_notes/

Answer (score 0):

I hit this issue as well and my app uses **xibs and storyboards** extensively.

I was able to get around the issue by pointing Xcode beta 6 to the asset compiler (actool) from Beta 5 which I still had on my machine. You will need to link to this version *(sample command:  `ln -s /Applications/Xcode-beta5.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/actool actool` from within your Beta 6/7 path).*

Unsure if this will cause any issue with app submission, but I confirmed that app on iOS 11 looks as it should again (light colors).

Comment: Apple just released Xcode 11 GM2 to resolve this issue.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_release_notes/